# Does there exist a complete metric space which is Rothberger (or Menger) but not Hurewicz?

Tags: gn.general-topology, selection-principles

A topological space $X$ is said to be a

1. Menger space if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there is a sequence $(\mathcal{V}_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal{V}_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{U}_n$ and $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{V}_n$ is an open cover of $X$.
2. Hurewicz space if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there is a sequence $(\mathcal{V}_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal{V}_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{U}_n$ and each $x\in X$ belongs to $\cup\mathcal{V}_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.
3. Rothberger space if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there is a sequence $(U_n)$ such that for each $n$ $U_n\in\mathcal{U}_n$ and $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n=X$.

I did not find an example of a complete metric space which is Rothberger (or Menger) but not Hurewicz.

Comment: I have already posted this question on MSE but did not get answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817583/does-there-exist-a-complete-metric-space-which-is-rothberger-but-not-hurewicz https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817530/does-there-exist-a-complete-metric-space-which-is-menger-but-not-hurewicz

Comment: If I remember well, a complete metric space is Menger iff it is $\sigma$-compact (shown by Hurewicz himself).  Hence a complete metric Menger space is Hurewicz.

Comment: @Mathieu [This](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01216792) should be the paper by Hurewicz in which the implication you mentioned is proved, but my German is a bit rusty. In any case more recently the result was extended to all Cech-complete spaces by [Tall and Tokgöz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04688)

Comment: If a metric space is a Rothberger space, then it is separable, and it contains no subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set. Hence a complete metric space is a Rothberger space if and only if it is **countable** and therefore a Hurewicz space. (I posted this as an answer which I deleted it because I saw it was already answered in comments.}

Comment: Definition 2.Hurewicz space, "but finitely many " -- is there a typo?